# Complex filter in path OpenAPI 3

Tags: java, openapi

I'm new in OpenApi 3. Would you help me to describe in yaml construction with complex filter?
Curl should look like  /...?page=0&size=10?filter=startDate=2005-08-09;endDate=2006-08-09;status:active,overdue,closed

for now i have in path:

```
parameters:
  - in: query
    name: page
    schema:
      type: integer
    required: true
    description: Number of page to display
  - in: query
    name: size
    schema:
      type: integer
    required: true
    description: The size of page
  - in: query
    name: filter
    schema: ???
```

Comment: Are you writing the OpenAPI file manually (as YAML/JSON) or generating it from source code? Can you post the definitions/code you have have tried so far (even if it did not work), so we have a starting point to help you from?

Comment: i try to write openapi file manually.